# Spark: Create JSON group by ID

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have dataFrame *unionDataDF* with sample data

```
+---+------------------+----+
| id|              data| key|
+---+------------------+----+
|  1|[{"data":"data1"}]|key1|
|  2|[{"data":"data2"}]|key1|
|  1|[{"data":"data1"}]|key2|
|  2|[{"data":"data2"}]|key2|
+---+------------------+----+
```

where *id* is IntType, *data* is of JsonType and *key* is StringType.

I want to send data over network for each id. For example, output data for *id* "1" is like:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "data": {
        "key1": [{
            "data": "data1"
        }],
        "key2": [{
            "data": "data1"
        }]
    }
}
```

How can I do same?

Sample code to create *unionDataDF*

```
val dummyDataDF= Seq((1, "data1"), (2, "data2")).toDF("id", "data");
val key1JsonDataDF = dummyDataDF.withColumn("data", to_json(struct( $"data"))).groupBy("id").agg(collect_list($"data").alias("data")).withColumn("key", lit("key1"))
val key2JsonDataDF = dummyDataDF.withColumn("data", to_json(struct( $"data"))).groupBy("id").agg(collect_list($"data").alias("data")).withColumn("key", lit("key2"))
val unionDataDF = key1JsonDataDF.union(key2JsonDataDF)
```

Version:

```
Spark: 2.2
Scala: 2.11
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
unionDataDF
  .groupBy("id")
  .agg(collect_list(struct("key", "data")).alias("grouped"))
  .show(10, false)
```

output:

```
+---+--------------------------------------------------------+
|id |grouped                                                 |
+---+--------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |[[key1, [{"data":"data1"}]], [key2, [{"data":"data1"}]]]|
|2  |[[key1, [{"data":"data2"}]], [key2, [{"data":"data2"}]]]|
+---+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: thanks for reply. What should I do after this step. While iterating using "for (row <- groupedDF.rdd.collect){}", I am encountering many "mutable.WrappedArray[Any]" type. Is this right way?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Send the data over network as JSON string? Can you send it from the executors or driver only? Batched etc?